# Is it advisable to have multiple singletons in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

I have read several articles discussing pros an cons about singleton patterns. But I would like to know:

> Is it advisable to have multiple singletons in an iOS App?

what are the pros and cons...?

Currently I am having only one singleton globally and holding strong references of other necessary properties including custom composite classes. But the idea sounds something strange for me for an example, accidentally I can create several instance of a custom composite class which I don't want.

Comment: It is totally up to you and what you feel comfortable with. Performance-wise it makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have as many singletons as you need. Take a look at `Cocos2d` - it contains a fair amount of them: `CCDirector`, `CCTextureCache`, `CCSpriteFrameCache` and so on. There's no limit on singletons, say 5. If it's convenient for you to have one single center class for a certain kind of operations (like accessing network or a database or whatever) and you never need a second instance of this class then feel free to make it a singleton.

Comment: thanks... short and sweet, but descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your requirement.
You can have multiple singleton classes or objects.

The singleton object will be alive till your application quits.
For memory managing concern, it'll be very difficult if you have multiple singleton objects(You can't release these singleton objects, when a memory warning raises).

Comment: +1 although you can instruct a singleton to free its internal data in memory low cases

Comment: @giorashc: yes, you can do that. But the meaning of singleton will be lost also. You can't create that object again if you are using `dispath_once`

Comment: I meant releasing the data stored in the singleton (via a proper singleton method, say releaseData() which will set proper members to nil or release them if not using ARC), not the singleton instance.

Comment: @giorashc: oh yes, you can do that.